# Mongoose filtering (search) on multiple fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, filtering

I'm trying to do a basic filter (search) on multiple fields, and would like to ask how to implement it:

```
Location.find({
          $and: [
            { name: { $regex: query.name } },
            { city: query.city },
            { type: query.type }
          ]
});
```

I had this for a start, but of course, this will filter on all fields and `$or` is not enough.

My data looks like this:

```
{ 
  "name": "Shop1",
  "type": "shop",
  "city": "City1"
},
{
  "name": "Shop2",
  "type": "shop",
  "city": "City1"
},
{
  "name": "Cafe1",
  "type": "cafe",
  "city": "City2"
}
```

The goal would be able to search entering a name, type and a city. (any field can be empty)

For example:

1. `Shop1 / Shop / City1 => Shop1`
2. `Shop / *blank* / City1 => Shop1, Shop2`
3. `*blank* / Shop / City1 => Shop1, Shop2`

and etc..

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to create query object by checking which parameter present or not

```
var queryCond = {}
if(query.name){
   queryCond.name={$regex:query.name,$options:"i"};
}
if(query.city){
   queryCond.city=query.city;
}
if(query.type){
   queryCond.type=query.type;
}
Location.find(queryCond);
```

In es6 you can do this nicely

```
let {type,city,name} = query;
queryCond = {
 ...(type && {type}),
 ...(city && {city}),
 ...(name && {name:/regex here/}),
}
```